# Honda Accord Head Bolt

Tags: repair, thread

I repaired one of the holes for a head bolt on my 97 Honda Accord using a time sert insert.  When I put the head back on I was only able to tighten it to 63 ft-lbs.  I could tell it wasn't going to tighten an more at that point and I stopped.  Anyone know what is the chance it will hold like that, without torquing it down all the way to 72? Since it's aluminium, I've read that they can't be repaired reliably.  Should I just try to find another engine block?  There might have been some cutting oil left in the new hole since I didn't clean it out all the way.  Which may be why I'm not able to torque it down all the way.

Comment: Wouldn't tighten anymore because you were afraid it would break or strip?

Comment: I was afraid it would strip, the torque stopped increasing at that point.  I'm using a torque wrench with a dial guage.

Comment: Why not take it apart, make sure the bolt hole is clear and try again?

Comment: If you did not clean the hole, more than likely it is hydraulic locked. In other words it cannot compress the fluid you left in the hole.

Comment: It wouldn't have that much oil in the hole to be hydraulic locked.

Comment: The block sat upside down for a few days after the hole was drilled.  I cleaned the bolt hole out with microfiber cloth and brushes.  There might have been enough cutting oil left to make the insert move while I was torquing the bolt down.  From the instructions I got that only the bolt was supposed to move and not the insert.  I'm just wondering if that torque will be good enough for normal driving or if I shouldn't even try.